# Linux: device appears in /dev but cannot be accessed

Tags: linux, driver, device

I have created a Linux device driver and can add it to the `system (insmod, mknod)`. When I look in `/dev` I see it listed as `camerax`:

```
ls -l /dev/camerax
crw-r--r--    1 root     root      245,   0 Jun 27 17:19
```

Even so, I cannot access it. Whatever I do, I get an error.

For example:

```
int fd = open("/dev/camerax", O_RDONLY);

printf("%d [%s]\n", fd, strerror(errno));
```

Generates:

```
-1 [No such device or address]
```

I'm running as a super user. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your Module is not linked to the special file which you have mentioned so it is giving error.

If your module is successfully inserted verify in /proc/devices using cat command

`cat /proc/devices`.

file created using mknod  in the path /dev/____ is just a refrence to your driver

The major and minor number should match with your inserted device.

Comment: I find it difficult to understand your answer. What is the "special file" you mention? The device appears in /proc/devices and the major and minor numbers match.

Comment: special file is an interface for a device driver that appears in a file system also called as device file.

Comment: You write "Your Module is not linked to the special file..." Is that not what "insmod Camera.ko" followed by "mknod /dev/camerax c 245 0" do? The 245 is confirmed from /proc/devices. If the module is not there, how come it appears in /dev? If I have misunderstood, please be more explicit in what you mean by "not linked".

Comment: For your information: mknod /dev/camerax c 245 0 will just create a file to access your driver.

Comment: If your driver is properly inserted into the kernel, the file created using mknod will be the point of refrence to your device driver with refrence to the major and minor number.

Comment: If the module is not there, how come it appears in /dev? 
module insertion and file creation using mknod both are different entity.

Comment: please refer Linux Device Driver book for your further refrence.

Comment: what you mean by "not linked".
special/device file is not refering to the driver which you are trying to access, and its not refrening to any driver. so it is giving error as  "-1 [No such device or address]".

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.

Instead of creating the major device number dynamically, as described in the documentation, I now set it explicitly to 61. Everything now works.

The only difference I can see between the working and non-working versions is the major number (and yes, I change anything that uses the device number so I am always using the appropriate one).

This adds one more bizarre feature of the system to my growing list.